Check if a runtime variable exists in TestSigma
I'm working with TestSigma and have encountered a scenario where I need to handle a runtime variable across different test cases. Here's my situation:
I have two types of forms that are functionally identical but are accessed through different methods.
I want to set a runtime variable (let's call it 'formApproach') at the start of each test case to indicate which method is being used.
Each form type should be tested in separate test cases.
I'm using a step group to encapsulate the common form-filling actions.
My challenge is: How can I check within the step group if the TestSigma variable has been set, and if not, set a default value?
Specifically, I need to:

Optionally set the 'formApproach' variable at the start of a test case.
In the step group, check if 'formApproach' has been set.
If it hasn't been set, assign a default value.
Use the 'formApproach' value (either the one set at the start or the default) to determine how to proceed with the form filling.

Here's a simplified flow of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Start Test Case]
  |
  +--> [Optionally set 'formApproach']
  |
  +--> [Enter Step Group]
        |
        +--> [Check if 'formApproach' is set]
        |     |
        |     +--> [If not set, assign default value]
        |
        +--> [Use 'formApproach' to determine form-filling method]
        |
        +--> [Execute form-filling steps]
        |
        +--> [Exit Step Group]
  |
[End Test Case]

Is there a way in TestSigma to implement this logic within a step group? How can I check and set a variable's value within the step group if it wasn't set at the start of the test case?
I used the natural language step to try and find a step which I could use, I could not find any. I also tried to use the if tool but I do not know what value to check for if it is set. I searched it online but did not find any helpful documentation.
